# How to implement selective automatic repeat request (ARQ) frame retransmission concept in simulink after detecting frame errors using CRC-4?

Tags: wireless

I have modelled an acoustic modem in simulink, i have used the CRC-4 (STD-ITU) scheme to protect the data for transmission, On the receiver end, the CRC decoder detects the errors in the received frames. I would like to send a request to the transmitter to retransmit this error frame, I am stuck at this part, Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Simulink Modem]